# Show all matches between two tables in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need help to show all matches between two tables in excel. I've searched everywhere and didn't find any answer yet.

Please check the table on the image.

***Table Sample:***
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: This could help : https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5242-excel-find-intersection-if-two-lists.html

Comment: i think, that only work for matching one cell in column, Thank you for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this (confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

```
IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$7=TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A$3),ROW($C$1:$C$6)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i need. Thank you so much for saving my day

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Set myNewRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ListObject(1).ListRows.Add
FOR i = LBound(Table1) TO UBound(Table1)
    FOR a = LBound(Table2) To UBound(Table2)
        IF Table1(i).Value = Table2(a).Value THEN myNewRow(i) = Table2(a).Value
        ENDIF
    NEXT a
NEXT i
```

Where myNewRow is the result table. You are going to have to use the nested for loop to accomplish this.

Comment: I haven't tried your answer yet, I think that would work, but I accepting the other answer that using formula. Thank you for answering,